# Why my service is not restart in some phone even return Service.START_STICKY?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-internet

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Log.e("Service", "Running");

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

My service is killed and didn't restart after task kill in vivo phones. But, Facebook app restart it's service in my phone. Why?
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        Intent myService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(myService);
    }
    else if(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent myService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(myService);
    }

    }
```

}
I start my service by using receiver..

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything in your service, if you are not doing any thing it obviously gets Garbage collected,

try

```
while(true) {

Log.d(TAG, "testing") 

}
```

in that service onStartCommand function, that should keep it running always

I would also recommend starting a Thread in side onStartCommand when OS kills the service, automatically service gets restarted.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (isRunning) {
             }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: I do my task inside onStartCommand function...But it`s ok in samsung phones but in funtoch OS ,Task killer kill both my process and service.My service cannot restart.Why should I do?

Comment: How are you starting the service, can you place the code for that